# How can I read the RID of a CDRW or DVDRW on Linux?

Tags: linux, security, dvd, data-cd

This question is inspired by [*this answer on SuperUser*](https://superuser.com/a/1828714/11116) by Proger_Cbsk.

The RID is the Recorder IDentification. It uniquely identifies the drive that wrote the CD/DVD.

What software if anything can read the RID written by a CD-RW, or DVD-RW? According to the linked answer,

> Oddly, the INCITS standard has a command to read the RID in a DVDR, but not for a CDR !

I would like to read the RID of a CD and DVD,

- DVDR: I would like to know how to issue the standardized command to read the RID
- CDR: I would like to do the same for CDRs. If this is drive-vendor specific, that is fine. I will purchase that drive.

Comment: There used to be a program called `pxlinux` that implemented the features of PxScan on Linux. But Plextor had gone a bit naff with their later drive and firmwares. These require a challenge-response protocol for non-standard commands (like disc quality check, which is needed for reading the raw data incl. the RID). While those commands can be reversed... that also allowed Plextor to claim they're DMCA protected... and send takedown notices for the software.

Comment: There's something called QPxTool https://qpxtool.sourceforge.io/snapshots.html which is probably the successor of that... but looking at screenshots I don't see it reporting the serial number of the writing drive (or even type), so it's not a full reimplementation of the Windows software. OTOH QPxTool supports non-Plextor drives for other features (like burn quality checks).

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer the part

> DVDR: I would like to know how to issue the standardized command to read the RID`

For DVD minus (R or RW), the standard-compliant SCSI MMC command to get the RID (actually "Drive manufacturer ID, Serial number and Model number") used to write on the disc is the `READ DISC STRUCTURE` with Format Code `0Ch` or `0Dh`.

Under Linux, you could use the `sg_raw` tool and send the following SCSI command (CDB):

```shell
sg_raw -r 32k <device> ad 00 00 00 00 00 00 0c 7f ff
```

Explanation:

> `ad` is the READ DISC STRUCTURE command
>
> `0c` is the Format Code (you may safely try `0d`)
>
> `7f ff` says to read up to 32k of datas.

Full detail over that command can be found in any "Mt Fuji Commands for Multimedia Devices" PDF (which succeeds the INCITS MMC and is freely available)

After successfully issuing the command, you'll get a dump of the Recording Management Data block (RMD), a boring long binary containing all tiny details about how the DVD was written. With any hex editor you can find, near offset 26624, in ASCII, the RID you're looking for. If you want to parse and understand the whole RMD, check the ECMA-338 standard PDF

Note: dont mess around `sg_raw`, always double-check the CDB you're sending, especially the two first bytes.